# I'm trying to insert SQL query but nothing inserting in database

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I'm trying to do simple script with PHP and insert some data, but nothing happens! I knew that I missed something but what is it?

This my code:

```
<?php
$host= "localhost";
$user="root";
$pass="freedoom19";
$db="dddd";

$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db) or mysql_error();

//====== Get Variable======= //
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$rate=$_POST['select_style'];
$content=$_POST['content'];

$insert="insert into reviews (name,email,rate,content) values ('$name','$email','$rate','$content')";

//====== Get Variable======= //
if($_POST['submit-comment'])  {
if($name && $email && $content == true) {

mysqli_query($con,$insert);
$success = "<span class='success_testmonial'>Thank You! .. Your Raiting Has Been Submitted And We Will Post It As Soon We Verify It !</span>";
}
else {

$error = "<span class='error_testmonial'>Error : one or some fields has left empty .. Please fill all field and try again.</span>";

}
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

And this it the form and the "action" ..

```
                        <form method="post" action="" id="form-contact" class="clearfix">
                        <div id="form-left">
                            <label for="text-name">Name *</label><br />
                            <input type="text" name="name" class="input" id="text-name" /><br />
                            <label for="text-email">From *</label><br />
                            <input type="text" name="email" class="input" id="text-email" /><br />
                            <label for="text-phone">Rate us *</label><br />
                            <div class="select-style">
                            <select>
                            <option value="5.0">5.0</option>
                            <option value="4.5">4.5</option>
                            <option value="4.0">4.0</option>
                            <option value="3.5">3.5</option>
                            <option value="3.0">3.0</option>
                            <option value="2.5">2.5</option>
                            <option value="2.0">2.0</option>
                            <option value="2.0">2.0</option>
                            <option value="1.5">1.5</option>
                            <option value="1.0">1.0</option>
                            </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="form-right">
                            <label for="text-comment">Review <span></span></label><br />
                            <textarea name="content" cols="10" rows="20" class="input textarea" id="text-comment"></textarea><br />
                            <input type="submit" name="submit-comment" class="button" value="Rate Us" />
                        </div>
                        <p id="text-contact">
                        <br><br><font color="#980303">Please Note *</font> Thate Your Reviews Will Not Published Untill We Check it and sure that the review don't contain Bad words or bad language, and be sure that we will publish all reviews and we accept criticism! 
                    </form>
```

So what I missed please?

Comment: no error message at all

Comment: yes, as you do not escape your variables, you might have a quote or something similar that breaks your insert query...

Comment: besides: `$name && $email && $content == true` are you aware of what you are doing in that line? This may be working, but I am sure you wanted some more strict checking..

Comment: try to escape your vars as is: $name = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);  just to be sure…

Comment: don't forget to turn on your error reporting in PHP and utilize `mysqli_error`

Comment: did it all and nothing happens

Comment: You should also check return value of mysqli_query to see if the query have been actually executed. As of now you just print success message even if the query failed.

Answer (score 0):

## Note:

- Put your insert query and passed on variables (POST) inside your if statement `isset(POST["submit-comment"]` to eliminate errors of *undefined variables*.
- You should use `mysqli_* prepared statement` instead to prevent [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

## Answer:

If you insist on retaining your code, you can use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` function to fertilize a bit the content of your variables before using it in your query.

Your PHP file should look like this:

```
<?php
$host= "localhost";
$user="root";
$pass="freedoom19";
$db="cookindoor";

$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db) or mysql_error();

//====== IF SUBMIT-COMMENT ======= //
if(isset($_POST['submit-comment']))  {
  if(!empty($_POST["name"]) && !empty($_POST["email"]) && !empty($_POST["content"])) {

    //====== GET VARIABLES ======= //
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['name']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email']);
    $rate = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['select_style']);
    $content = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['content']);

    $insert="INSERT INTO reviews (name,email,rate,content) VALUES ('$name','$email','$rate','$content')";

    mysqli_query($con,$insert);
    $success = "<span class='success_testmonial'>Thank You! .. Your Raiting Has Been Submitted And We Will Post It As Soon We Verify It !</span>";
  }

  else {
    $error = "<span class='error_testmonial'>Error : one or some fields has left empty .. Please fill all field and try again.</span>";
  }
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

## Recommendation:

But if you execute it in `mysqli_* prepared statement`, your insert query would look like this. Though this is just a simple example but still executable:

```
if($stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO reviews (name, email, rate, content) VALUES (?,?,?,?)")){ /* CHECK THE QUERY */
  $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $_POST["name"], $_POST["email"], $_POST["rate"], $_POST["content"]); /* BIND VARIABLES TO YOUR QUERY */
  $stmt->execute(); /* EXECUTE YOUR QUERY */
  $stmt->close(); /* CLOSE YOUR QUERY */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to put your get variables inside the if else statement
check if there are datas in POST when done submitting:

```
if($_POST['submit-comment'])  {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $rate=$_POST['select_style'];
        $content=$_POST['content'];

        $insert="insert into reviews (name,email,rate,content) values ('$name','$email','$rate','$content')";

        if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }

        var_dump($_POST);
}

$con->close();
```

check for errors:

```
$check = mysqli_query($con,$insert);
var_dump($check);
```

if you found one, let me know

Comment: if you found one, let me know

Answer (score 0):

Check this working code. Also you had not set element name for `Drop down` as `select_style`. It was throwing error for that too.

PHP Code

```
if(isset($_POST['submit-comment']) && $_POST['submit-comment']!='')  {

  $host= "localhost";
  $user="root";
  $pass="";
  $db="test";

  $con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db) or mysql_error();

    //====== Get Variable======= //
    $name  = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['name']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email']);
    $rate  = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['select_style']);
    $content = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['content']);

  $insert="insert into reviews (name,email,rate,content) values ('$name','$email','$rate','$content')"; 

  if($name && $email && $content == true) {

    mysqli_query($con,$insert);
    $success = "<span class='success_testmonial'>Thank You! .. Your Raiting Has Been Submitted And We Will Post It As Soon We Verify It !</span>";
    echo $success;
  }
  else {

    $error = "<span class='error_testmonial'>Error : one or some fields has left empty .. Please fill all field and try again.</span>";
    echo $error;

  }

  mysqli_close($con);
}
```

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="" id="form-contact" class="clearfix">
<div id="form-left">
  <label for="text-name">Name *</label><br />
  <input type="text" name="name" class="input" id="text-name" /><br />
  <label for="text-email">From *</label><br />
  <input type="text" name="email" class="input" id="text-email" /><br />
  <label for="text-phone">Rate us *</label><br />
  <div class="select-style">
  <select name="select_style">
  <option value="5.0">5.0</option>
  <option value="4.5">4.5</option>
  <option value="4.0">4.0</option>
  <option value="3.5">3.5</option>
  <option value="3.0">3.0</option>
  <option value="2.5">2.5</option>
  <option value="2.0">2.0</option>
  <option value="2.0">2.0</option>
  <option value="1.5">1.5</option>
  <option value="1.0">1.0</option>
  </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="form-right">
  <label for="text-comment">Review <span></span></label><br />
  <textarea name="content" cols="10" rows="20" class="input textarea" id="text-comment"></textarea><br />
  <input type="submit" name="submit-comment" class="button" value="Rate Us" />
</div>
<p id="text-contact">
<br><br><font color="#980303">Please Note *</font> Thate Your Reviews Will Not Published Untill We Check it and sure that the review don't contain Bad words or bad language, and be sure that we will publish all reviews and we accept criticism! 
</form>
```